# Read .epub File While Being Uploaded

Tags: javascript, filereader, epub

When I upload a .epub file into my browser I want to be able to open it, grab the cover image and save it separately from the .epub itself.

In order to do this I am using [react dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) and [futurepress epub reader](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/). In the README it says:

"On most recent browsers versions, the files given by onDrop won't have properties path or fullPath. If you want to access file content you have to use the FileReader API"

Here is my current code:

```
onDrop(acceptedFile) {
  for (var i = 0, f; f = acceptedFile[i]; i++) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(reader) {
      return function() {
        const contents = reader.result;
        const Book = ePub(contents);
        console.log(Book);
      }
    })(reader);

    reader.readAsText(f);
  }
}
```

When I try to upload an .epub file I get -- "referenceError: href is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The FileReader API onload event has a different synopsis:

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
    // showing the text of the file
    console.log(event.target.result)
};
```

so I suggest to change like this:

```
onDrop(acceptedFile) {
  for (var i = 0, f; f = acceptedFile[i]; i++) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(event) {
      return function() {
        const contents = event.target.result;
...
```

Comment: How is the `ondDrop` function called?